# Copy a file to another folder when last update was 1 hour (Google App Script)

Tags: google-apps-script

I have several shared Drives where I am the owner and would like to have a script to check the last update / save time and if it is 1 hour or more to then copy the file to another Shared Drive. I also need it to make sure it is not creating duplicates of the same file.

I have got so far with this and the copy element and checking for duplicates is fine - just trying to see a way of modifying this so that it can check the last update / save of a file and then do the copy.

I would have a trigger set to run every hour. Here is the current code:

```
  function CopyFiles() {
 var srcFldr = DriveApp.getFolderById('PASTESTUDENTGOOGLESHAREDDRIVEIDHERE')
//The above is the URL of the Google Shared Drive of the student exam account
var srcFiles = srcFldr.getFiles();
var desFldr = DriveApp.getFolderById('0ACWWE8dc-XThUk9PVA')
//The above 0ACWWE8dc-XThUk9PVA is the Google Shared Drive called Exam Archives. DO NOT CHANGE
var desFiles = desFldr.getFiles();
var dfnA = [];
var key = "fileIDs";
var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
var property = scriptProperties.getProperty(key); // Retrieve fileIDs property
// Get array of fileId, or empty array if no file has been copied before:
var arrayIDs = property ? JSON.parse(property) : []; 
while (desFiles.hasNext()) {
 var df = desFiles.next();
 dfnA.push(df.getName());
  }
 while (srcFiles.hasNext()) {
  var sf = srcFiles.next();
// Check not only file name, but also whether fileId has been stored before:
 if (dfnA.indexOf(sf.getName()) == -1 && arrayIDs.indexOf(sf.getId()) == - 1) {
  sf.makeCopy(sf.getName(), desFldr);
  arrayIDs.push(sf.getId()); // Add fileId to array of IDs
 }
 }
scriptProperties.setProperty(key, JSON.stringify(arrayIDs)); // Store updated array
}`
```

Any suggestions?

Have adjusted the code before but not able to make it check the last update / save of a file and then do the copy (with no extra duplication)

Comment: Hi. You covered a lot of ground there but I rather lost track of exactly what is your problem. Would you please clarify.